# C: Adding data from text file into a singly linked list

Tags: c, file, singly-linked-list

I'm recently started learning C programming. I have some java experience so I know my way around codes, I like to think..
This little thing I'm working on is killing me.
I'm trying to make a program that read lines from a text file -> store it in a singly linked list -> print out the singly linked list
This is my code so far:

```
typedef struct node {
    char *data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node *start = NULL;
node *current;


void add(char *line) {

    node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    // This line under I believe where my problem is...
    temp->data = line;
    temp->next = NULL;
    current = start;

    if(start == NULL) {
        start = temp;
    } else {
        while(current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = temp;
    }
}
```

This is my function for reading the file and sending characters to the add function

```
void readfile(char *filename) {
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if(file == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }

    char buffer[512];

    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file) != NULL) {
        // I've tried to just send i.e: "abc" to the add function
        // which makes the program work.
        // like: add("abc");
        // my display method prints out abc, but when I'm sending buffer
        // it prints out nothing
        // Thing is, I've spent way to much time trying to figure out what
        // I'm doing wrong here...
        add(buffer);
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

I'm sure this is a fairly simple problem, but I've spent way too much time with this problem.
And if there is anything other that look off/could be better I appreciate feeback on that aswell :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
temp->data = strdup(line);
```

to `dup`licate (make a copy of) what line points at.

Otherwise every line points at the `buffer` which is getting overwritten with each new line.

Comment: That fixed the problem! Thank you for replaying so fast

Comment: Note that strdup is not part of the ANSI C standard(and deprecated on windows). (For the assignment I'm guessing this is for though, you should be okay, just make sure you understand what happens as `strdup()` does a `malloc()` which you need to `free()`).

Answer (score 4):

You need to allocate memory for the string - each line is read into buf and so you need to copy it out or it will be overwritten with subsequent lines. I suggest one of two approaches, the first being the simplest with what you already have, but the second being better as you only need to do one free() for each object.

The first one is just a single change to your add() function:

```
temp->data = malloc(strlen(line)+1);
strcpy(temp->data, line);
```

Now, when you want to free an object in your linked list you must first call free() on data and then free() on the object itself.

However you can change the structure slightly and then you can allocate the whole object in one go:

```
typedef struct node {
  struct node *next;
  char data[0];
} node;
```

Then your add() function would look like this:

```
void add(char *line) {

  node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node)+strlen(line)+1);
  strcpy(temp->data, line);
  temp->next = NULL;
  current = start;

  if(start == NULL) {
    start = temp;
  } else {
    while(current->next != NULL) {
      current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = temp;
  }
}
```

Note that of course you should do error checking after each malloc() in production code. When you are done with an object a single free() is enough to free the whole structure.

Edit: The "array length 0" feature is a GCC specific extension, as noted by @crashmstr in the comments. If you use an array length of 1, it should work in any compiler though:

```
typedef struct node {
  struct node *next;
  char data[1];
} node;
```

Since an extra byte is already allocated in this case, the malloc() call in the add() function would then become:

```
  node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node)+strlen(line)+1-1);
```

(of course the +1-1 can be omitted, but it is just to show that we still need space for the null terminator but an extra byte is already included in the sizeof).

Comment: Of course you can also do what John Hascall suggests above - it's a shorthand for the first version, I just did it explicitly for pedagogic value. strdup() does exactly the same as the malloc/strcpy pair above, (and returns NULL if the malloc fails).

Comment: The second options looks like a GCC extension [Arrays of Length Zero](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html), and I would avoid using it.

Comment: @crashmstr you are right, I've used it enough times that I mistook it for a standard feature. It's best avoided for portable programs. You could do it with an array of length 1, or with the C99 syntax in the article you quote.